# Need help understanding code execution, for nested for loop

Tags: python-3.x

I have trouble understanding the element wise execution of the following code. The goal is to define a function, that returns the cartesian product of 2 sets. The problem should be solved using the methods in the code below.

I have tried looking up similar problems, but since i am new to programing and python i get stuck easy.

```
A = {1,2,3,4}
B = {3,4,5}
```

```py
def setprod(m1,m2):
    p=set()
    for e1 in m1:
        for e2 in m2:
            p.add((e1,e2))
    return p
```

`setprod(A,B)` returns `{(1, 3), (3, 3), (4, 5), (4, 4), (1, 4), (1, 5), (2, 3), (4, 3), (2, 5), (3, 4), (2, 4), (3, 5)}` The cartesian product is the set containing all the ordered pairs of elements of the two sets. The elements in A can be choosen 4 diffrent ways and B 3 giving 4x3=12 combinations.

I just can`t see why the code above accomplishes this.

Comment: What is exactly confusing to you? The first loop iterates elements of `A` (the next item is in `e1`) and the second loop does the same for `B` (item is `e2`). Then it adds the `(e1, e2)` tuple to the result set in each iteration. I suggest you to follow the loops and try to do the same thing the code does using a pen and paper.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to a debugging tool (perhaps you could install pycharm and use its debugger) you can see what's going on.

Let's step through what's going on in the code together mentally.

```
A = {1,2,3,4}              #Step 1, load a set (1,2,3,4)
B = {3,4,5}                #Step 2, load a set (3,4,5)
def setprod(m1,m2):        #Step 4, define the function
    p=set()
    for e1 in m1:
        for e2 in m2:
            p.add((e1,e2))
    return p
setprod(A,B)               #Step 5, execute function with parameters
```

At this point if we want to see what setprod does we step into the function.

```
    p=set()                #Steppedin, step 1 create empty set
    for e1 in m1:          #Steppedin, step 2, begin forloop iterating through m1, 
                           #which contains (1,2,3,4); e1 is set to 1

        for e2 in m2:      #Steppedin, step 3 begin inner for loop 
                           #iterating through m2, which contains (3,4,5), 
                           #e2 is set to 3, e1 contains the value 1

            p.add((e1,e2)) #Stepped in, step 4.  add (m1[0],m2[0]), represented by 
                           # (e1,e2) to the set.
    return p
```

At stepped in step 4, the next step is the same line of code but with different register values, e2 is no longer m2[0] but m2[1]

```
            p.add((e1,e2)) #Stepped in, step 5.  add (m1[0],m2[1]), represented by 
                           # (e1,e2) to the set where e1 = 1 and e2 = 4
```

.

```
            p.add((e1,e2)) #Stepped in, step 6.  add (m1[0],m2[2]), represented by 
                       # (e1,e2) to the set where e1 = 1 and e2 = 5
```

At this point we return to the parent for loop.

```
    for e1 in m1:          #Stepped in, step 7.
                           #use m1[1] as e1 and repeat previous process but 
                           #with the new e1 value set to 2

        for e2 in m2:      #Stepped in, step 8.  e1 contains 2, e2 is set to 3
            p.add((e1,e2))
```

(Just a note, if you were debugging this, I believe you'll only see the values for e2 and e1 when you are at the section of the code p.add, saying that e1 is set to some value at #stepped in, step 7, isn't completely accurate but is helpful enough for looking at the idea of what is happening.)

Comment: Thanks for a very informative answer my problem was understanding how the code fixes a element in the outer loop and iterates through elements in the inner while adding those combinations to the new set. This is the process i would do for hand, turns out your explanation of the code is identical to it.